# Rationalize a surd $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: irrational-numbers

How can I rationalize the following surd
$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}$$
What would be the conjugate of the denominator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rationalise twice, because after rationalising once , there would still remain a surd in the denominator.

First multiply and divide by $1+\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}$

$$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}\times\frac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}$$
$$= \frac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{1+2\sqrt{2}+2-3}=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Now multiply and divide by $\sqrt{2}$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}+2+\sqrt{6}}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $(1+√2)=a,√3=b$ and then rationalize it . i assumed so as denominator is simpliefied as $2.√2$

Comment: Which can easily be rationalized then

Answer (score 2):

Use twice the conjugate:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}} &= \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{3}}\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{3}}{(1+\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\\
&= \frac{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{4}
\end{aligned}$$